# Instalação Pacote mgarch no R

Tags: r

Quero instalar o pacote `mgarch`. Fiz o download por [aqui](https://github.com/vst/mgarch/).

Parece que preciso  instalar o **devtools** como é explicado [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9656016/how-to-install-development-version-of-r-packages-github-repository).

Faço tudo isso e não consigo.

Como posso resolver este problema?

Eu faço o seguinte procedimento:

```
install.packages("devtools")

library(devtools)

dev_mode(on=T)

install_github("mgarch")
```

A pasta mgarch é criada em: C:\Users\Meunome\Documents\R\win-library\3.1

logo em seguido eu faço o comando:

```
library("mgarch")
```

e diz que não existe tal pacote.

Comment: O que seria "não consegue"? Quais erros são entregues a você?

Answer (score 1):

Supondo que o `devtools` foi instalado corretamente, você precisa usar o comando:

```
library(devtools)
install_github("vst/mgarch")
```

e não `install_github("mgarch")`.

`mgarch` é o nome do repositório no github, mas todo repositório tem um dono, neste caso é o `vst`.

Veja o link: https://github.com/vst/mgarch

Comment: Sim Daniel.... depois de ``library(devtools)` e `install_github("vst/mgarch")` acontece isso:

Comment: `Downloading github repo vst/mgarch@master
Installing mgarch
"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.0/bin/x64/R" --vanilla CMD INSTALL  \
  "C:/Users/Diogo/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpKeGY5L/devtools28fc650e497c/vst-mgarch-788d77b"  \
  --library="C:/Users/Diogo/Documents/R/win-library/3.1" --install-tests

Comment: * installing *source* package 'mgarch' ...
** libs

*** arch - i386
Aviso: execução do comando 'make -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.0/etc/i386/Makeconf" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.0/share/make/winshlib.mk" SHLIB="mgarch.dll" OBJECTS="loglikelihood.o loglikelihood_GJR.o matrixlib.o"' teve status 127
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'mgarch'
* removing 'C:/Users/Diogo/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/mgarch'
Erro: Command failed (1)

Comment: Já tentou instalar o RTools? http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/
Normalmente esses pacotes com códigos em linguagens compiladas precisam dele. No linux não é necessário, mas no Windows as vezes precisa.

Comment: Ja Daniel......

Comment: quanto de memória RAM tem o seu computador?

Comment: Bom, consegui. Tive que reinstalar o Rtools...muito obrigado pela a ajuda pesssoal.